# Undefined module in angular-meteor tutorial

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I am trying to follow along with the angular-meteor.com tutorial for Angular 1. I keep getting the following error when trying to convert it to component syntax in [step 3](https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/3-way-data-binding/)

I thought it was a typo somewhere so I tried downloading step 3 from git and still having same error!

```
modules.js?hash=451e0fb…:755Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module socially due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module undefined due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'module' is not a function, got undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue here, I think it's due to not properly removing the ecmascript package as instructed in [Step 0](https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/bootstrapping)

As soon as I followed the step-by-step instructions on removing and adding the correct packages it worked.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please describe the answers more. when you have a link in your answer, it is probable that the page get removed and your answer get useless for other people in the future